# MonoDroid Capturing Mouse Positions

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monogame

I'm currently helping someone out with an XNA to Android port for the game FlyTrap. You can check out a video of the game here: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhwCErELHoA

The port is going pretty well, except for one thing. The guy who hired me is building an arcade machine, based off a cubieboard2, his plan is to attach two arcade joysticks. Apparently the arcade joysticks he has imitate a Mouse on Android.

The plan is to capture the position of the mouse every frame, calculate a delta value between this frame and the previous frame, and use that delta to direct player movement. The problem is Mouse.GetState doesn't seem to work. So I'm thinking I will have to work on a Mono.Android level instead of a MonoGame level.

Long story short, does anyone know how to capture the position of a mouse in Android?

Angus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked two questions in this post. I'll start with the easier one. "So my next question is, how can I get AndroidGameWindow to implement View.OnGenericMotionListener?"

The project I was working on was targeting Android API8, Views.OnGenericMotionListener came about in Android API12. In Xamarin Studio I right clicked on the project, chose Options.

- Under Build --> General I set the target framework to Android API 12
- Under Build --> Android Application I set the Minimum Android Version and the Target Android version to API 12.

In the MonoGame project in the file Android.AndroidGameWindow I added these two methods

```
public bool OnGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent e)
{
    return OnGenericMotionEvent(e);
}

public override bool OnGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    MousePosition.X = e.GetX();
    MousePosition.Y = e.GetY();

    return true;
}
```

I also modified the AndroidGameWindow class so that it implements the interface Android.Views.View.IOnGenericMotionListener

Answer (score 2):

mplement `OnTouchListener` in your Activity and set the Listener for your View using the `setOnTouchListener()` method.

Now you can override the `onTouch()` method in your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

int x = (int) event.getX();       
int y = (int) event.getY();

return false;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but this only triggers an event when I click on a mouse. I actually want an event to fire whenever I am moving the mouse. So I figured out the right thing to use is View.OnGenericMotionListener. 

That means I will to modify AndroidGameWindow so that it implements View.OnGenericMotion Listener. The problem is I cannot find the interface, I realized it must be because I am API8, when I need a minimum of API12. 

So my next question is, how can I get AndroidGameWindow to implement View.OnGenericMotionListener?

Comment: Starting from android 4.0 you can receive events for hover with a mouse via: View.setOnHooverListener().

Check http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html

in the section "Hover events".